# Shopify - Can a customer generate an RMA number for returning products?

Tags: shopify

Is it possible for a customer to log into their account on a Shopify store, in order to notify us of a return they'd like to make?

Ideally, a user would click on the item they want to return from their order history and receive an automatic RMA number which they can write on the package.

Is this at all possible? I've scoured the Shopify docs, but I can only find information on how to make returns on the shop side of the process.

https://help.shopify.com/manual/orders/refund-cancel-order

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: As there is no built in functionality in shopify that can help you with your requirement , Either you need to build an app for yourself or use a third party app. I would suggest you to check these apps
[Return Manager](https://apps.shopify.com/returns-manager)
[Returnly](https://apps.shopify.com/returnly)
[Automated RMAs and Returns](https://apps.shopify.com/automated-rmas-and-returns) beta

Comment: @MashR. Oh that's a shame there's no built in mechanism or API. Thanks for the suggestion, I'll look into it.

Comment: Shopify has api, then you will have to develop a private app for it.